# Find out if account is locked using terminal

Tags: catalina

I need to detect if a user has locked their account on Catalina ( for example by typing an incorrect password x times). Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pwpolicy getaccountpolicies -u usershortname` - if the account is disabled it will return *"Error: Credential verification failed because account is disabled."*

For example:

```
[root@macOS] / #pwpolicy disableuser -u admin
Disabling account for user <admin>
[root@macOS] / #pwpolicy getaccountpolicies -u admin
Getting account policies for user <admin>
Error: Credential verification failed because account is disabled.
[root@macOS] / #pwpolicy enableuser -u admin
Enabling account for user <admin>
[root@macOS] / #pwpolicy getaccountpolicies -u admin
Getting account policies for user <admin>
[root@macOS] / #
```

Comment: Thank you, quick question is disabled is the same as locked on MacOS? I'm coming from windows and it's different there

Comment: I guess it is the same - if a non-admin user exceeds the `maxFailedLoginAttempts` the account will be disabled and they can't log in.  See for example [Using pwpolicy to Manage User Password Policies via CLI](https://www.afp548.com/2004/09/27/using-pwpolicy-to-manage-user-password-policies-via-cli/)